# Symfony2 REST : Boolean types interpret json 0 as true

Tags: json, symfony, boolean, fosrestbundle

I am using FosRestBundle and I'm confused about how to save false when a field is a boolean. As the values are always set to 1 when I save.

My json is

```
{"cancelled":0}
```

If I do this in my controller, it saves as 0 as expected

```
if( $request->request->get( 'cancelled' ) === 0 ) {
    $request->request->set( 'cancelled', false );
}
```

But why do I have to do that, shouldn't the integer 0 be interpreted as false?

Comment: Well, why should integer `0` interpret as false at all? Why shouldn't it interpret as `0`?

Comment: I mean, you should transform the value *after* it's bound to an underlying data model. E.g. your entity's `setCancelled()` should do the transformation, or the request should be bound to a form that would handle this transformation.